# Check every time a selector's parents has class (i.e. active) then call a function

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('.tiger2').parents().hasClass("active")){
      /* when add active class then */
      /* only one time this alert or a function is cassed */
      alert("1");
    }
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.parents2').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.active{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>When ON click Add a class than get the style</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parents1 active">
      <div>
          <div class="tiger1"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="parents2">
      <div>
          <div class="tiger2"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <button>Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Do Something** when **adding class by javascript/Jquery**
All the time *check* **a selector's** has **parents**, **active class**, then call a function
I already use this its works but I won't satisfy

```
**var count = true;
function myFunction() {
    setInterval(function(){
        if(*$('.tiger2').parents().hasClass("active")* && count){
            alert("1");
            count = false;
        } 
    }, 1000);
}
myFunction();**
```

[check me on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Md_Ashfaqur_Rahman/dL930uxu/1/)

Comment: Why not just run your code when you add the class?

Comment: _I already use this its works but I won't satisfy ..............._ complete the sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no readymade way to fire an event when the class is changed. But what you could do is trigger a custom event everytime you update the class and this could in turn perform the desired activity.

For example :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.parents2').toggleClass('active');
        // Only fire if "active" class is present after toggle
        if($('.parents2').hasClass('active'))
           $(document).trigger('classActiveAdded');
    });
    $(document).on('classActiveAdded', function() {
    alert("1");
    });
});
```

```css
.active{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>When ON click Add a class than get the style</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parents1 active">
      <div>
          <div class="tiger1"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="parents2">
      <div>
          <div class="tiger2"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <button>Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You very much, You almost solve my code problem.
but one thing please I don't wont to alert when removing the class
please check the link
https://jsfiddle.net/Md_Ashfaqur_Rahman/dL930uxu/2/

Comment: Sorry to say Actually I am new in here so would you please told me how to do that

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: You are welcome. Please do mark the response as an Answer.